# Strip HTML tags which are incomplete

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am developing a blog using php pdo, mysql and i am using CKEditor. If i choose to write a blog post using 'source' option available in CKEditor which is nothing but writing html code directly without using editor.

I am having an issue with this, If by mistake an user write an incomplete html code, for example user forgets to close a div or span, it is reflecting entire site and the layout is being changed. Is there any solution for this if an user writes an incomplete html code in editor should not reflect the website just like wordpress does.

Example of incorrect code

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #0000ff;">List of Links.</span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong><a class="lbp_secondary" style="color: #ff0000;" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Click here for Google</a></strong></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong><a class="lbp_secondary" style="color: #f
```

Please help me

Comment: Its obviously inefficient to do it this way, but would counting the number of `<` and `>` work? For example, you parse everything, and find a `<`. And you find another `<` before there is a `>`. Then it is probably a broken tag.

Please note though, that your user won't be able use **<** in their text.

Answer (score 0):

count all `<.*>` tags and `</.*>` tags (use `preg_match` functions). if they are not identical strip tags